# how to convert first letter of an input box to upper case which also contains Numeric value using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an address field in my registration page which contains both numeric and letters, I want to change the first letter to upper case.
Can anyone give me some javascript code to do so..

for example.

```
1. wallmart street ..Output -> Wallmart street
2. 221,wallmart street.. Output -> 221,Wallmart street.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function foo(val)
{
    return val.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/, function(letter) {
        return letter.toUpperCase();
    });
}
```

Comment: ..here "wallmart street" is not fixed..it can be anything and was used just as an example.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
function changeCase(what)
{     
    var val
    if(what!=null){val= what.value};
    if(val!=null && val.length>0)
    {
        what.value=val.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+val.substring(1,val.length);
    }     
}
```

Comment: In my example we have numeric values at chatAt(0)..so how will it change that to upper..we first somehow need to find the first character from the string,this is where I am struggling to get this.

Answer (score 0):

This function will take a string, change the first character occurrence to uppercase, and return the string.

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function(){
    var self = this.split('');
    for( var i=0; i < self.length; i++ ){
        if( /^[a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜ]+$/.test(self[i]) ){
            self[i] = self[i].toUpperCase();
            break;
        }
    }
    return self.join('');
}
```

Use like so.

```
var title = "1. wall street";
title = title.capitalize();
```

Comment: @Will..thanks for the response but your code is not helping. It is not  changing any letter.

Comment: How are you calling it?

var capitalizedString = capitalize("1. wall street");

Comment: I edited my answer with a prototype example, and example of it being called.